# DragDockPanel problem with Silverlight 5 beta?

Tags: silverlight-5.0, backlight

Has anyone have problem with using Silverlight 5 with backlight's DragDockPanel?

When I have DragDockPanel or add a DragDockPanel in the DragDockPanelHost, there will be java script error :

```
Line: 56
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2028    
Category: ParserError       
Message: The name already exists in the tree: PART_TopLeftClip.     
File:      
Line: 0     
Position: 0
```

I wonder if anyone also have this problem?

I am developing a new project and was going to use the DragDockPanel for the main display menu... But as I know the Backlight project had been stopped, I wonder if there is any replacement for this control?

Thanks in advance,

King

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple Silverlight 5 test project, and added the following to the MainPage:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <blacklight:DragDockPanelHost>
        <blacklight:DragDockPanel>
        </blacklight:DragDockPanel>
        <blacklight:DragDockPanel>
        </blacklight:DragDockPanel>
    </blacklight:DragDockPanelHost>
</Grid>
```

And that worked in fine in FF4 and IE8 on Windows 7 Professional x86.  The 2 dock panels were displayed and could be dragged and maximized/minimized fine.  What version of the blacklight library are you using?  I am using 2.5.0.0.  I assume you changed the target silverlight version of the blacklight project to be Silverlight 5.